# DRF url doesnt work when i add parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

i created this API to retrive session_data based on session_key from the table django_session.
i get the requested behavior with the session_key as a static field, like in the below code and this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXyI6.png)

```
#urls.py
path('session_data/',views.get_session_data,name='session_data'), 
#views.py
@api_view(['GET'],)
def get_session_data(request):
    session_key='pirxxzoh3rifjqch403ro8nfmkzmg972'
    response_content=decode_session_data(session_key)
    return JsonResponse(response_content,safe=False)
```

once i change my code by adding a paramter str:session_key to urls.py and to the get_session_data, i get 404 Not found response.
here is the code:

```
@api_view(['GET'],)
def get_session_data(request, session_key):
    #session_key='pirxxzoh3rifjqch403ro8nfmkzmg972'
    response_content=decode_session_data(session_key)
    return JsonResponse(response_content,safe=False)
```

and for urls.py i tried both and it didnt work.

```
path('session_data/<str:session_key>',views.get_session_data,name='session_data'),      
path('session_data/<str:session_key/>',views.get_session_data,name='session_data'),
```

[first_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXMfg.png) [POSTMAN_ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6wzz.png) [another_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFtFL.png)
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is two things mixed: using a parameter to built an url or to pass a parameter to a "fix" url.
In the first case the call has no "?" and parameter is catched in the urls.py path:

```
Http://server/...../page/xyz/...

Path   "... /page/<str:parameter>/..."
```

In the second case paramater is added with "?" and extracted in the view from the request:

```
Http://server/...../page?parameter=xyz.

Path  " ... /page"
```

Comment: i want to pass the parameter to a fixed case, i tried 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/session_data?session_key=123
and i kept getting: 
TypeError at /api/session_data
get_session_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'session_key'.

Comment: Your view "def get_session_data(request, session_key):"  needs the path like I showed as first case then everything should work. If you send the session key as you show it in your comment it will be in the request and your view is missing the second argument "session_key" .

Answer (score 0):

My workaround this was to simply send the session_key in the body instead of using parameters.